# Paragraph breaks inside tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, paragraphs

I have a document full of nicely formatted and separated paragraphs (each separated by two line breaks in the source), which is working nicely. Now I'd like to put some of them into a `tcolorbox`.

But when the text is inside a `tcolorbox`, all paragraph breaks are replaced by simple line breaks!

Is there a way I can get normal formatting inside a `tcolorbox`?

MWE (I'd like the first three and last three paragraphs formatted the same):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[5]

\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like `tcolorbox` redefines `\parskip`, but adding it inside the `tcolorbox`, e.g. after `\begin{tcolorbox}`, fixes the issue.

Comment: @marmot So it does! Is there a way to automatically prepend that to every one of my `tcolorbox`es? If so that would make a good answer, and I'd accept.

Comment: Whether you separate your paragraphs in the source by one or by twenty-seven blank lines will change nothing in the output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the `parbox` key to false:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false]
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[5]

\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I cannot give you an answer that works for all imaginable `tcolorbox` variations as these can have upper and lower and you-know-not parts (I'm exaggerating a bit, I know;-). However, for your simple scenario one way to smuggle the desired `\parskip` (or whatever setting) inside the `tcolorbox` is to say `\tcbset{before upper=\setlength{\parskip}{1em}}`. Whether or not a more universal way exists, I don't know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\tcbset{before upper=\setlength{\parskip}{1em}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[5]

\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]